# Reverse for ''*'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to use the `{% url %}` tag to send my user to a new template, called payment.html. I am receiving the error above. Here's what I have:

In some Javascript in my template:

```
  {% url 'payment' %}
```

In my urls:

```
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^pc-admin/', include(pcAdminSite.urls)),

    (r'^$', index),
    (r'^signup/', signup),
    (r'^info_submit/', info_submit),
    (r'^payment/', payment, name="payment"),
```

In my views:

```
  def payment(request):
    return render_to_response('payment.html', {})
```

Based on similar posts, I've made sure that only 1 URL points to my payment view and have used named URLs. Can anyone help with what I might be doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There shouldn't be any `''` surrounding the view name in the `url` tag - check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url) out. 
(Unless you're using the Django's 1.5 `future` `{% url %}` tag.)

Comment: Thanks, that was one issue. The other was there was somehow a duplicate of the urls.py file in my project and I was editing the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

this error also occurs this way :

```
<a href="{% url 'profiles_profile_detail' user.username %}">My account</a>
```

the message will be this one

```
Reverse for ''profiles_profile_detail'' with arguments '(u'mynick',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

once the two '' dropped like explain erlier everything works fine ;)